# Getting onActivityResult in Audio Intent

Tags: android, avaudiorecorder

I need to record an audio using inbuilt audio recorder in android and upload that file to server. i recorded an audio using audio recorder intent but i could not able to get the onActivity Result. can anyone help me please? I am using Samsung Galaxy S.

Answer (score 0):

When I preform an activity as you have stated, I always do the higher of the two then the latter, if both return successful then I integrate the two into 1 Activity. Attempt this test:

1: Record and save Audio to SD (to ensure that your recording is present) then
2: (Using a second Activity) Attempt to upload that File to your server.

If the test is successful, integrate the 2 activities. I hope this helps as you have not provided any code to be reviewed.